# Jquery selecting images in a link in and out of a table then adding to fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have some database generated html that contains images when the user clicks a link / thumbnail i'd like these to be displayed in a fancybox

if the thumbnail are in a table i'd like to group them into a Simple image gallery like the example [here](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/)

If it is just a link to an image within some text I'd like it to be show  as single image in the fancybox like one of the  "Different effects"

However if the links are just links then they should remain unaffected

I'm have a spot of bother with the jquery selectors can someone point out the error

Also is it possible to add a zoom feature to the image within the fancybox without the need to link to another larger version of the image?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>fancyBox - Fancy jQuery Lightbox Alternative | Demonstration</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

        <!-- Add jQuery library -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Add mousewheel plugin (this is optional) -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>

        <!-- Add fancyBox main JS and CSS files -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../source/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.0.6"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.0.6" media="screen" />

        <!-- Add Button helper (this is optional) -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.2" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.2"></script>

        <!-- Add Thumbnail helper (this is optional) -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.2" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.2"></script>

        <!-- Add Media helper (this is optional) -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.0"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
       var iTabNum=0;
        $(document).ready(function() {

          $('a > img').each(function(){

            if($(this).parent('table'))
              {
              var TabID;
                  if (typeof($(this).parent('table').attr('id')) == "undefined" )
                     {
                      iTabNum ++;
                      $(this).parent('table').attr('id', "img" + TabID + iTabNum);
                     }
                  else
                     {
                       TabID = "img" + $(this).parent('table').attr('id'); 
                     }
                $(this).closest().attr('class', "fancybox");
                $(this).closest().attr(TabID + '-group', "gallery" );

              }
            else
              {
              $(this).attr('class', "fancybox-effects-d");

              }


        });

            $('.fancybox').fancybox({
          overlay : {
                css : {
        //  hover > img{width:100px;height:100px;z-index:1000;position:relative;top:-50px;left:-50px;},
                    'background-color' : '#eee'
                }
          }});

        $(".fancybox-effects-d").fancybox({
                    padding: 0,

                    openEffect : 'elastic',
                    openSpeed  : 150,

                    closeEffect : 'elastic',
                    closeSpeed  : 150,

                    closeClick : true,

                    helpers : {
                        overlay : null
                    }
                });          
    });

      </script>
      </head>
      <body>
            <div>
              <table>
                <tr>
                  <td><a  href="1_b.jpg" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"><img src="1_s.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                  </td>
                  <td><a  href="2_b.jpg" title="Etiam quis mi eu elit temp"><img src="2_s.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><a  href="3_b.jpg" title="Cras neque mi, semper leon"><img src="3_s.jpg" alt="" /></a></td>


                  <td><a  href="4_b.jpg" title="Sed vel sapien vel sem uno"><img src="4_s.jpg" alt="" /></a></td>

                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h3>Etiam quis mi eu elit</h3>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,  <a href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/">www.fancyapps.com/fancybox/</a> consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam <a href="5_b.jpg" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit">Image</a> quis mi eu elit tempor facilisis id et neque. 
                </p>
        </div>

      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: So, can't you add the `fancybox` class beforehand?

Comment: Unfortunately not not without doing a complex SQL statement to update the HTML stored in the database

Comment: Regarding "add a zoom feature", the fancybox buttons helper includes a button to see the image in its real size when the image was down-scaled to fit in the viewport

Comment: Are you refering to the size toggle?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your question but basically what you want is:

- Assign a different `ID` to each table so the links to images (with thumbnails) inside that table belong to the same gallery.
- Any link to an image should either get `class="fancybox-effects-d"` or `class="fancybox"` under the following conditions:

  - `fancybox-effects-d` for links to images **outside** a table and/or links to images **without** a thumbnail regardless they are inside a table or not.
  - `fancybox` and the same `rel` attribute for links to images **inside** a table (`rel` attribute should match the table's ID and different from other tables) AND **with** thumbnails.
  - Other links (not to images) whether inside a table or not should remain unaffected.

So if you have more than one `table`, each `table` should look like

```
<table id="img1"></table>
<table id="img2"></table>
```

then each link **outside** of a `table` should look like:

```
<a class="fancybox-effects-d" href="image01.jpg"><img src="image01thumb.jpg" alt="" /></a>
<a class="fancybox-effects-d" href="image02.jpg">image 02</a>
<a href="http://example.com">link somewhere else</a>
```

and links **inside** of a `table` should look like:

```
<table id="img1">
 <a class="fancybox" rel="img1" href="image03.jpg"><img src="image03thumb.jpg" alt="" /></a>
 <a class="fancybox" rel="img1" href="image04.jpg"><img src="image04thumb.jpg" alt="" /></a>
 <a class="fancybox-effects-d" href="image05.jpg">image 05</a>
 <a href="http://example2.com">another link</a>
</table>
<table id="img2">
 <a class="fancybox" rel="img2" href="image06.jpg"><img src="image06thumb.jpg" alt="" /></a>
 <a class="fancybox" rel="img2" href="image07.jpg"><img src="image07thumb.jpg" alt="" /></a>
 <a class="fancybox-effects-d" href="image08.jpg">image 08</a>
 <a href="http://example3.com">another link</a>
</table>
```

If all of the above is correct, then you could simplify your scripts like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 // assign a different ID to each table
 $('table').each(function(i){
  $(this).attr('id', 'img'+(i+1));
 });
 // go through all <a> tags
 $('a').each(function(i){
  // get the parent tag name
  var parentTag = $(this).parents()[0].nodeName;
  // detect if link has thumbnail
  var hasThumb = $(this).children().html();
  // detect if the link targets to an image, otherwise ignored
  if(this.href.match(/\.(jpe?g|gif|png|bmp)((\?|#).*)?$/i)){
   // since the parent of an element inside a table is (should be) "TD" 
   // then evaluate if the link is inside a table
   // AND it has a thumbnail
   if(parentTag == "TD" && hasThumb != null){
    // get the parent table's ID
    var TabID = $(this).closest("table").attr("id");
    // set the class and rel attributes
    $(this).attr({"class":"fancybox","rel": TabID});
   }else{
    // if link to an image has not a thumbnail AND/OR is outside a table
    $(this).addClass("fancybox-effects-d");
   }
  }
 }); // each
}); // ready
```

You could tweak the script to fit your needs.

BTW, the correct syntax for one of your fancybox scripts should be:

```
 $('.fancybox').fancybox({
  helpers : {
   css : {'background-color' : '#eee'}
  }
 });
```

(you omitted the `helpers` option)